# How can a Vendor Invoice No (a PO#) number be set on a purchase order via v2 of the Microsoft Business Dynamics API?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

Before a purchase order can be received and invoiced a 'Vendor Invoice No' must be set, in systems where it's set to be required, which in my case it is, however I see no way of accomplishing that via the API. I have not found any documentation on where to set this number via the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I assume that "v2 of the Microsoft Business Dynamics API" means API v2.0 of Dynamics 365 Business Central. The answer follows this assumption.
There is no API available to set the vendor invoice no. in BC purchase orders. Although, there is a suggestion to add it on [Microsoft Idea](https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=a2007f14-136d-ee11-a81c-000d3ae6c59b). It's good to upvote it if you are interested, but it does not look to be very popular.
Your immediate solution would be to take a copy of the API page from the [Business Central extensions repository](https://github.com/microsoft/ALAppExtensions/blob/main/Apps/W1/APIV2/app/src/pages/APIV2PurchaseOrders.Page.al), add the required field, and publish it as a [custom API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-develop-custom-api).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! We ended up setting the Vendor PO via an OData query and endpoint